# Claims Based Application Not redirecting to STS

Tags: security, claims-based-auth, security-token-service

I have setup my Claims Based application along with my STS. I have setup the STS as the token issuer in the Powershell. I can view the STS and everything in the browser, but when I try to go to the SharePoint application it redirects to a different location rather than the STS.

Any ideas as to why it goes here? this doesn't even exists and I have it setup to use "default login page"

```
:8081/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F
```

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the trusted identity token issuer in SharePoint, you provide a sign-in url: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806864%28v=office.14%29.aspx